# Difference between mmol/l and mg/dl for blood glucose measurement

Tags: blood-tests, measurement, glucose

I'm in the process of preparing a short lecture on hypoglycemia. In the process, I discovered that blood glucose levels can be expressed in the measurement of millimoles per liter or milligrams per deciliter.

I did find one question here on Medical Sciences S.E. that was related to this. However, it doesn't completely answer the question I'm about to ask. I have tried to research this using Google but didn't come across any resources that were helpful in answering the following...

Are there any countries that exclusively use mmol/l or mg/dl? If there are, what countries are these?

I'm wondering if this is a similar situation to the US vs most other countries. The US still uses the English units of measure - inches, pounds, Fahrenheit - while most other countries use the metric system.

The related question here on S.E. did answer my question about why this system is used at times. But I wasn't able to find anything there about what other countries do or don't use it.

Comment: *"The US still uses the English units of measure."* ummm....some of us English people use imperial measurements as a preference but a lot of professions use metric in an official sense much to the annoyance of those who can only visualize in imperial measurements.

Comment: Welcome back ^^. I haven‘t actually seen anyone use mmol/l here in Germany, but my experience is solely limited to hospital capillary glucose tests (always in mg/dl) and lab tests (so far I‘ve solely seen them in mg/dl). However, it is pretty hard to prove that either version is the only used measurement in a country/region...

Comment: Personally I've always seen mg/dl in the US (probably the only context anyone ever talks about a deciliter of anything) - do you see mmol/L?; as Narusan said, easier to prove both are used than to prove one is not.

Comment: I've never seen mmol/l used anywhere in clinical medicine in the US. The only place I've seen it is research articles, which are by nature international. I think the US is an example of a country that uses mg/dl exclusively, but I don't know how to prove it because it requires proving something doesn't exist, which is nigh impossible.

Comment: @ChrisRogers No offense intended. I meant that as a generalization. The general population of the US uses Fahrenheit for their weather forecasts, for example. And most of the rest of the world uses Celsius for their weather forecasts. I know that this isn't entirely across the board, but I figured it would be a good example of what I was trying to ask.

Comment: @L.B. No offence was taken :-) I was just pointing something out which you may not have been aware of.

Comment: In NZ we use mmol/l for our personal meters, but, the Labs always use mg/dl for their reports and I can never remember the conversion and always have to look it up, which takes me ages!

Comment: @Eric the conversion should be related to the relative volumes and molar mass.  Molar mass of glucose is 180.156 and a decilitre is 1/10th of a litre. As mass = number of mol * molar mass, the conversion should be mmol/l * molar mass * 0.1 litres. I think, - I'm no mathematician though.